# java swing setting frame background color not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to create a tic tac toe game using java swing. I created a frame and set its background to a color. The problem is that the background color of the frame is not changing, I tried using other colors but the background color is always white.
here is the code:

```
public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener {
    Random random = new Random();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel title_panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel button_panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel textField = new JLabel();
    JButton[] button = new JButton[9];
    boolean player1_turn;

    TicTacToe () {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);


        textField.setBackground(new Color(0x084887));
        textField.setForeground(new Color(0xF58A07));
        textField.setText("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        textField.setFont(new Font("Ink Free",Font.BOLD,75));
        textField.setOpaque(true);
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);


        title_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        title_panel.setBounds(0,0,800,100);


        title_panel.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(title_panel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attempt to set the background of the content pane:

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

But then you add the "title panel" to the frame:

```
frame.add(title_panel);
```

So your title panel completely covers the content pane.

**You need to set the background color of your title panel.**

Other issues with the code:

1. Don't use setBounds() on a component. The layout manager will determine the size/location of each component.
2. You should only invoke the setVisible(...) method AFTER all components have been added to the frame.
3. You should `pack()` the frame before making the frame visible. This will ensure all components are displayed at their preferred sizes.
4. The GUI should be created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`.

Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). The section on `Concurrency` will explain why this is important. All example in the tutorial will demonstrate how to make sure code is on the EDT.